# Creating new content redirects to PAGE NOT FOUND

Tags: nodes, 7

When I create content, regardless of the content type, I am redirected to a page not found error message even though the page is created. Can you please help? I got this message:

Page not found Add URL redirect from this page to another location The requested page "/node/5191" could not be found.   This happens regardless of the content type. I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Enable the field_ui module and that error will disappear - why the field permissions overview page is being invoked for a node add page I have no idea, though

Comment: @Clive Your comment looks like the data that used to be in the question was somehow good and useful. Now I'm tempted to vote to put on hold as unclear or too broad and ask for clarification. But maybe it should be rolled back? I'll leave it for now.